# How and why is a private shared value within an instance of a class surviving between http requests?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net

We have a large asp.net application (written in vb.net). All of our bespoke classes are stored in App_Code folder as .vb files.

One of these classes is behaving very strangley - specifically, its private members are surviving between http requests - even after the constructor has been called.

Let me give you a simplified example, the class is massive, but the class declaration is perfectly routine:

```
'#### App_Code/Common/xxxUtilities.vb
Public Class xxxUtilities
    Private Shared m_ajax As Boolean = False
    Public Class CommonHTML
        Public Sub Whatever()
            '#### Share the value of m_ajax here
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

We have a typical aspx codebehind page located elsewhere declaring an instance of this class in the usual way - lets call it default.aspx:

```
Public SF As New xxxUtilities(db, CurrentUser)
```

There is also a seperate aspx page (used in ajax operations - lets call it ajax.aspx) that has its own codebehind page with this same code - i.e. its own instance of the class - or so we thought!

Whats happening is this (verified with debugger):

1. **default.aspx** is loading, instance of `xxxUtilities` is created normally, the `m_ajax` member remains `false`
2. **default.aspx** calls **ajax.aspx** with jQuery, **ajax.aspx** creates (what we thought was) its own instance of `xxxUtilities` and sets `m_ajax` to `true` - then returns normally.
3. When we next refresh **default.aspx** and step through the code, it creates a new instance of `xxxUtilities` as normal - passing values to the constructor - yet to our amazement, `m_ajax` is true?!?!?

This raises three questions:

1. How & why is `m_ajax` true in the last step? was the ajax instance left in memory and when the follow-up default.aspx requested a new instance, it just links to the existing one or something?
2. Is there a way of ensuring any instances of custom classes are completely disposed of at the end of the http request?
3. We have the same issue with a database class (Again, located in App_Code), if we forget to call `.CloseDatabase()`, the connection stays open to the SQL server, even after the http request ends - is this the same issue? i.e. is the instance of the database class being left in memory after the http request ends?)
4. How do we modify (i.e. real-world code / example) default.aspx / xxxUtilities.vb to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: `Shared`/`static` are *not* your friend when it comes to multi-threaded and web based code. As Eric points out, it will persist through all contexts as it is not related to any specific instance of that class.

Comment: @TyCobb: Way back in the .NET 1.1/.NET 2.0 days we used to use `static` for caching application data.  Now there are far better methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Shared` keyword is the same as the `static` keyword in C#.  It means that the field so decorated is associated with the class, not with an instance of a class.

The storage will survive until the app domain is reset.

> How & why is m_ajax true in the last step? was the ajax instance left in memory and when the follow-up default.aspx requested a new instance, it just links to the existing one or something?

The instance has left memory, but a Shared field is not associated with an instance.  Note that *all* HTTP requests that are currently running will see the *same* m_ajax field.  This may cause concurrency issues as currently coded.

> Is there a way of ensuring any instances of custom classes are completely disposed of at the end of the http request?

Don't use a Shared field.

> We have the same issue with a database class (Again, located in App_Code), if we forget to call .CloseDatabase(), the connection stays open to the SQL server, even after the http request ends

Open and close your database connection with the [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statement within the code that handles each HTTP request.